# How to display Events in Calendar page

Tags: symfony, fullcalendar

Im working in symfony2.5 framework.
In my app, i have a calendar page implemented with full calendar.js jquery plugin. (http://fullcalendar.io/).
I have a event table with records of employees' events.

How to display these events in the calendar page.

my calendar page's js:

```
$( '.calendar' ).fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next,today',
            center: 'title,',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        }
});
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2):

First you have to parse your events as fullCalendar event object, following [event documentation](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Object/)

```
var myEvent = {id: 1, title: 'myTitle', start: moment(...)}
```

Then, you should add those events to an array, function, json...

```
var mySourceEvents = [myEvent, myOtherEvent];
```

Finally you could set that array in your fullcalendar config as a source.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    eventSources: [
        mySourceEvents
    ]
});
```

Or... You could add your events directly as an array:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: [
        {
            title  : 'event1',
            start  : '2010-01-01'
        },
        {
            title  : 'event2',
            start  : '2010-01-05',
            end    : '2010-01-07'
        },
        {
            title  : 'event3',
            start  : '2010-01-09T12:30:00',
            allDay : false // will make the time show
        }
    ]
});
```